# Why are gauge theories called so?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, gauge-theory, history

Why are [gauge theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory) called so? I guessed it was because gauge also means to estimate, so when one is trying to find the gauge theory for such and such interactions one has to estimate what might be the best gauge group for that interaction. Does this make sense?

Comment: In a book I have written by Leonard Susskind he says: _It is called a gauge transformation. Why "gauge"? Its a historical glitch. At one time it was wrongly thought to reflect ambiguities in gauging lengths at different locations._

Comment: Would [hsm.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic That's the same question I asked myself. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about history, not science, and should be on history of science and mathematics.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because Weyl's original gauge theory (1918-1920), which was also the very first unified field theory of electromagnetism and gravity (Kaluza only published in 1921), had a field of scales/gauges needed to completely localize Riemannian metric, see [When and how was the geometric understanding of gauge theories developed?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-and-how-was-the-geometric-understanding-of-gauge-theories-developed/147#147) Weyl's prototype was general relativity, but as it is Riemannian geometry is not completely local. Lengths of vectors at different points are numbers, and can be compared in the absolute sense. Weyl's idea was that all measurements must be relativized to local scales only.

So he replaced Riemannian with conformal metric, and added a field of scales instead of absolute scalars, the gauge field. This gauge field specifies how the scales are transported, but not minimally, different fields may specify the same transport, in which case they are related by a gauge transformation. Weyl's theory did not work out (Einstein quickly noticed that it was unphysical), but the gauge idea had a bright future. Weyl's principle of gauge invariance stated that the form of physical laws must be invariant under local gauge transformations. Selecting a particular version of a gauge field among many equivalent ones is now called ["fixing the gauge"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing), the Lorentz gauge for the vector potential is an example.

Thus, the first gauge group was $\mathbb{R}^+$ of positive reals under multiplication, in late 1920s Weyl went from a field of gauges to a field of phases, replacing $\mathbb{R}^+$ with $U(1)$, but the name stuck. In this new theory Weyl was able to give  a gauge theoretic explanation of the conservation of electric charge. Dirac replaced the $U(1)$ fields with the sections of  associated complex line bundles in 1931, and noticed the possibility of magnetic monopoles when the bundles were globally non-trivial. Non-Abelian gauge theories did not appear until Yang and Mills in 1950s.

Varadarajan's paper [Vector Bundles and Connections in Physics
and Mathematics](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~vsv/papers/paper.pdf) is a good historical survey of early gauge theory, with technical details.

Comment: Did not Weyl explicitly call his invariance "Eichinvarianz" and the English word is simply a calque of this one?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Yes, and Eich is calibration/gauge/scale in German. But modern gauge theories are closer in spirit to the $U(1)$ version, so it should really be phase theory, phase fixing and phase invariance :)

Comment: @Conifold Just a note in passing : Weyl did not adapt his theory to U(1) group until London and Schrödinger proved it might give a nice playground for the newly discovered quantum mechanics. See the book *The Dawning of Gauge Theory* by O'Raifertaigh, and a review by the same author on Review of Modern Physics.

Answer (score 0):

I think the name is very good if you think about how you can make measurements in a gauge theory. For example, take a distance in general relativity one can't measure the distance without some physical system of rulers and clocks or some other "physical coordinates" that we use to locate physical events and describe directions. Ultimately when we measure things we have to read the values off from some dial such as a clock or look at the number on a tape measure. In electromagnetism the same thing is true. What we do in practice is measure the potential difference with a physical volt meter from which we can read off a number with physical meaning. So the general theme of gauge theories is that you need some physical object "a gauge" which then allows one to read off a physical reading. The reading one gets in the end depends on which gauge one uses hence the ``gauge field'' e.g. the metric tensor or the gauge potential are not themselves observable. Really what one measures is a relation between the device used to make the measurement and the gauge field. In the literature, these constructions are called "dressed observables" or "relational observables". One can of course construct these without thinking about measurements per se and hence "the gauge" is often thought of as dressing which takes a gauge variant field and makes it gauge invariant. Ultimately physics is an experimental science though so in the end we have to read off values from some device or other. I think no one understands why nature is described by gauge theories (it is just an experimental fact) but I think this understanding points towards a deeper understanding that might be useful when we think of going beyond our current theories (but that is pure speculation). Anyway, to say it is a "historical glitch" seems to lack some understanding or a desire to understand better. I think this paper discusses the point well https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5599.